# Using Google Maps geometry library in nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-maps, geometry

I want to use the Google Maps geometry library within a nodejs application.

From what I can see this library is only available with the Google Maps Javascript api. Is there a way for me to do this?

Colin Goldberg

Answer (score 5):

you can try following modules  available online

1. **spherical-geometry-js**
       **npm i spherical-geometry-js**
   This library provides classes and functions for the computation of geometric data on the surface of the Earth.
   This library ports a small but useful subset of classes from the Google Maps Javascript API version 3, to use as a separate module or in node.
   **Notes:**
   The API is nearly identical to the Google Maps Javascript API.
   Functions automatically convert coordinate objects into LatLngs. See convertLatLng for more details.
   All computed lengths are returned in meters.

you can import whole 
      **import * as geometry from 'spherical-geometry-js';**
Or import individual modules
     **import { computeArea } from 'spherical-geometry-js';
       import computeArea from 'spherical-geometry-js/compute-area';**

full description can checkout here 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/spherical-geometry-js

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,
https://www.npmjs.com/package/spherical-geometry-js

This NPM package has all geometry functions.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can download geometry code and use it offline. Or use any node.js API implimentations like [this](https://github.com/moshen/node-googlemaps). But you should make sure that it does not violate Google policy (if you care about it).

Comment: Watch out. The google-maps  loader pointed in the answer is only usable from the browser.

Comment: Thans, Julien, you are right, I updated link in my answer.